# How to exit an iPhone app if the terms are rejected?

Tags: iphone, xcode, exit

When the user selects "Reject" on my Terms and Conditions page, I'm able to display an alert, but I can't figure out how to exit from the application completely. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you implement let's say a code lock and always display it when your app enters the screen, you can exit the app by `exit(0)` if the user fails to enter the correct code in 3 tries or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple discourages apps from quitting themselves—it gives the user the impression that the app has crashed—and based on the fact that I've never seen an app display terms-and-conditions nonsense when it starts up, I'd guess that that's a surefire way to get your app rejected from the Store in any case. iTunes Connect allows you to provide custom license text when you're submitting the app; I'd recommend just using that.

Comment: Just show only an "Accept" button. Reject is that round button below the screen. This will be accepted by Apple.

Comment: Exactly, if a user does not choose to accept they can just quit the app.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this challenge and thanks to @Noah Witherspoon I found how to set a custom license in order to be shown before  downloading the app from AppStore. Please refer page 52 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) in order to see what would happen when you do that.